# can we move sql compact edition database to sql lite database in windows forms application

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce, database-migration

Currently I am using an SQL Server Compact Edition database in a Windows Forms application.

Now I have to move the database to SQLite. Is it possible to move the database from SQL Server Compact to SQLite? If it is possible, what are the steps we have to follow?

Answer (score 1):

I have tools to export the SQL Server Compact file as a .sql script - that would get you half of the way - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks for ur valuble suggissiions